# Where do I want to travel this year?

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

This year I would like to travel, but only to countries respecting a specific condition. It would be fine for me to travel to Qatar, but not to France. I could have some days in Chad, but not in Japan. Maybe I will even drop in Tuvalu, but certainly not in Mali.

EDIT: China is also not a country in which I want to go this year.

Could you find another country where I could land this year and explain why?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A princely port you may land in is

> HAITI

This follows the rule that the

> first letter of the country immediately precedes the last letter of the country as given by
>
>  QataR , ChaD , TuvalU and this seems rare.

Answer (score 6):

You could also go to

> Zambia

if you allow

> wrapping around the end of the alphabet.

Otherwise I think Tom has the only answer.

Comment: I thought about accepting it as an additional answer, so it's a good answer too!

Answer (score 4):

This answer is probably wrong, but it does fit.

I think you could go to

> Greenland

Because

> The countries you want to go to had less than 14.5 million inhabitants in 2016, and the countries you don't want to visit had more than that.

Comment: This was not the good answer, but that was a nice idea too!

Answer (score 2):

Well you can travel to

> Italy

But not to

> Germany

Explanation:

> I based my answer on lip movement, if your lips don't touch saying the country you can go (although "France" was borderline depending on how much you force the "f" sound)

Comment: This is not the good answer, but I'm still curious how you found this answer.

Comment: I based my answer on lip movement, if your lips don't touch saying the country you can go (although "France" was borderline depending on how much you force the "f" sound)

Comment: That was a fair answer, but not what I was looking for. I added another city in which I couldn't go to prevent this.

Comment: They're called labial consonants. "F" is one, but so is "V," which disqualifies "Tuvalu".